# PHP regex: Modifying tag to tag + content

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following to use htmlentities on anything inside of a `code` tag:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('#\<code\>(.+?)\<\/code\>#s',create_function('$matches','return "<code>".htmlentities($matches[1])."</code>";'),$content);
```

This way I can echo it out onto the page. This works great, other than it only works if the code tag is exactly `<code>`. How can I update the regex so that it will work with the contents inside of `<code + anything + >`?

For example:

```
<code>
<code class="someclass">
<code class="someclass" data-attr="value">
```

Comment: If you must use regex ~ `#<code(.*?)>...`. Also, PHP has anonymous functions

Comment: @Phil I'd like to see how this is a duplicate of that other question. And even if it was, there doesn't seem to be a clear answer on that linked question. There are dozens of answers with dozens of opinions for a question that is not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: the pattern has to exclude >, see my answer.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with these anonymous functions. Care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Urgh, I'm really sorry about that. Was meant to link to this post ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('#(\<code[^>]*\>)(.+)\<\/code\>#s',create_function('$matches','return $matches[1] . htmlentities($matches[2])."</code>";'),$content);
```

I'm not clear on why < and > are being escaped in your pattern, is that necessary? Try removing the escapes there to make it: `(<code[^>]*>)`
It should work fine I think.

Note that `\<code[^>]*\>` means: `<code` plus anything that is is not `>` then close `>` as a match.

You're now getting two matches:`(\<code[^>]*\>)`and `(.+)`and using them to create your result.

Note that (.+?) makes little sense, you probably want: (.*) which means 0 or more instances of anything, then the pattern has to find a closing code tag after that anything. This works well if there is only one `</code>`possible in the input value, if there can the more than one, you will  run into problems because the pattern will probably read all the way to the last one.

This is the version I'd use. (.*) handles the case where there is nothing between the code tags.

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('#(<code[^>]*>)(.*)</code>#s',create_function('$matches','return $matches[1] . htmlentities($matches[2])."</code>";'),$content);
```

Comment: I have no idea. I'm not good with regex at all.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you know how I would now preserve the original `<code[^>]*\>` instead of replacing with `<code>`?

Comment: You shouldn't need it, usually you escape characters that are used like # to begin / end the regex pattern. Or \s, etc, \t, and so on.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help

Comment: no problem, regex is hard to learn. Try it without the escapes so you don't get into bad habits though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133508/discussion-between-jrob-and-lizardx).